# Swagger definition not displaying as expected

Tags: java, dropwizard, swagger-ui

I have the following piece of code and swagger is not showing up the way i expect on swagger ui. I'm using annotations to build the swagger definition. I tried using @API and @JsonIgnore. Both did not work for me.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlRootElement;
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;


@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "traction")
@Api(hidden = true)
public class Traction
{
  private JsonNode traction;

  public JsonNode getTraction()
  {
    return traction;
  }

  public void setTraction(final JsonNode traction)
  {
    this.traction = traction;
  }

}
```

Swagger definition gets displayed as follows -

```
"tractionParent": {
    "traction": {
      "array": false,
      "null": false,
      "float": false,
      "containerNode": false,
      "missingNode": false,
      "nodeType": "ARRAY",
      "valueNode": false,
      "object": false,
      "pojo": false,
      "number": false,
      "integralNumber": false,
      "short": false,
      "int": false,
      "long": false,
      "double": false,
      "bigDecimal": false,
      "bigInteger": false,
      "textual": false,
      "boolean": false,
      "binary": false,
      "floatingPointNumber": false
    }
  }
```

I need it to show up as

```
"tractionParent": {
    "traction": {
     }
 }
```

Comment: Swagger shows all fields of a type. JsonNode looks like that inside, thus swagger 'expects' you to set them. If you really need just empty braces, then make traction of type Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same problem recently and solved it by registering a custom `ModelConverter` which maps a `JsonNode` to the [free form object](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/#free-form) for swagger

```
class JsonNodeProperty extends AbstractProperty {
    protected boolean additionalProperties = true;

    public JsonNodeProperty() {
        setType("object");
    }

    public boolean isAdditionalProperties() {
        return additionalProperties;
    }

    public void setAdditionalProperties(boolean additionalProperties) {
        this.additionalProperties = additionalProperties;
    }
}

class JsonNodeModelConverter implements ModelConverter {
    @Override
    public Property resolveProperty(Type type, ModelConverterContext context, Annotation[] annotations, Iterator<ModelConverter> chain) {
        JavaType javaType = Json.mapper().constructType(type);
        if (javaType != null) {
            Class<?> clazz = javaType.getRawClass();
            if (JsonNode.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)) {
                return new JsonNodeProperty();
            }
        }
        if (chain.hasNext()) {
            return chain.next().resolveProperty(type, context, annotations, chain);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Model resolve(Type type, ModelConverterContext context, Iterator<ModelConverter> chain) {
        if (chain.hasNext()) {
            return chain.next().resolve(type, context, chain);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

You can register the custom converter via

```
ModelConverters.getInstance().addConverter(new JsonNodeModelConverter());
```

Comment: I think I have the same issue. Where should I get ModelConverter? Is this from springfox-swagger2? what version ?

Comment: @user3441604 I used the converter from swagger core. Documentation: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/overriding-models

Answer (score 0):

You have taken  'traction' variable type JsonNode that why you are getting all properties of Class **com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode**.
For more detail you visit on link   [JsonNode Class](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/master/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.java)  to view the Source code

Comment: i understand this. i just want to ignore them and not display in the swagger definition

Comment: Facing similar issue, can't swagger recognize JsonNode field like it does for String and other types?